# Visual Basic Compiled Executable Database Connection Issues

Tags: oracle, vb6

I'm at a loss. I'm attempting to run a VB6 compiled executable that connects to a networked oracle database. If I run the program with a full compile inside VB6, there are no issues. If I compiled an executable, I can run the program but when it attempts to connect to the database it gives an error the database can't be found. If I put this same executable on a local share and a colleague executes it, they can connect to the database without issues. Ideas?

Comment: What is the exact error message the connection string? Which provider do you use?

Comment: If you could update your question to include the code which connects to the DB, including the connection string, that would be very helpful.

Comment: so it turns out it's actually related to permissions. I moved the compiled executable on to my local c: drive and it worked. originally I was running from a personal share drive.

I'm not at the office at the moment or I would update with the code - never really thought it was code related in the beginning which is why I didn't include from the get go - but big thanks for the replies. :)